# Building index vector by using two vectors where first contains start indeces, second end using R

Tags: r

I have two vectors:

```
startIdxes<-c(1, 5, 12, 22)
endIdxes<-c(2, 9, 17, 25)
```

The vectors presents ranges e.g 1:2, 5:9 ...
How I can build index vector using this two vectors?
The index vector should be:

```
> c(1:2, 5:9, 12:17, 22:25)
 [1]  1  2  5  6  7  8  9 12 13 14 15 16 17 22 23 24 25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` to get the sequence between corresponding values in both `vector`s and `unlist` the `list` output.

```
unlist(Map(`:`, startIdxes, endIdxes))
#[1]  1  2  5  6  7  8  9 12 13 14 15 16 17 22 23 24 25
```

The function `Map` is

```
Map
function (f, ...) 
{
  f <- match.fun(f)
    mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
}
```

---

Another option is getting the difference between the two vectors, adding with the replicate of 'startIdxes' with the `sequence` of difference, concatenate with the original 'startIdxes' and `sort`.

```
i1 <- endIdxes - startIdxes
sort(c(startIdxes, rep(startIdxes, i1) +  sequence(i1)))
#[1]  1  2  5  6  7  8  9 12 13 14 15 16 17 22 23 24 25
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mapply`

```
unlist(mapply(seq,startIdxes,endIdxes)) 

#[1]  1  2  5  6  7  8  9 12 13 14 15 16 17 22 23 24 25
```